# Javascript Regular expression with replace

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I'm working on a project on search about `emoji` and `replace` it with icon
but I have some problem on `regular expression`, Below mentioned is my code for reference:

```
var f = ["( :3 )" , "( :P )","\(:star:\)"];

var re =  function(s){return new RegExp(s, 'g');};
```

now when I'm going to search about `emoji` and `replace` it as shown below:

```
s = "hello :D how are you :P dwdwd";
for(var n in f){    

var m; 
if ((m = re(f[n]).exec(s)) !== null) {

m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
  s = s.replace(match,"<img src='http://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/"+ r[n] +".png'>");
});

}}
```

In this case, it works well and replace the `emoji`. But it only replace when there are space before and after `emoji` what should i do to replace the `emoji` in the begin of string or end !

```
s = ":D hello how are you :)";
```

This case is not working. How can i edit my `regular expression` for being able to replace `emoji` at begin and end of string and at the same time if its found in middle of string & have space between word and `emoji`

My 2nd problem with `regular expression` is `"\(:star:\)"` it never replaces. While it must replace word `:star:` with an `emoji` but i think i miss some thing on `regular expression` for it.

Comment: First, its not a good idea to use `for..in` on objects

Comment: @Rajesh why its a loop same as `(var i =0; ...... )`

Comment: `for..in` is meant to loop on properties of object. So in old browsers, `for..in` will also iterate over `.length` property

Comment: @Rajesh yea you are right :D but i think little of people have old browsers

Comment: By old browsers, I mean Chrome 50 or so. I'm not talking about IE 6 or 7. Modern browsers have added a patch to avoid such `.length` property. So no matter what I will not suggest using `for..in` with array.

Comment: You can use `for...of` instead, if I'm not wrong

Comment: @MohamedMohamed What is the issue? If I'm right, your code is not converting `":P"` but its converting `" :P "`. Right

Comment: Could you make your code clearer by indenting/formatting it properly and finding meaningful names for your variables? Quite hard to understand what `f`, `re`, `s`, `n` and `m` are supposed to hold... Also, could you provide what `"hello :D how are you :P dwdwd"` should be replaced with at the end?

Comment: just remove the spaces in `( :3 )` -> `(:3)`

Comment: And to add to the request from @sp00n, you don't even mention the variable `r`.  Is that some list of names that's supposed to be parallel to `f`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet its another array for emoji path not important :)

Comment: try [this](https://regex101.com/r/WnYPY7/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use beginning & ending anchors along with pipe to achieve this. For example:

`/(^:3\s)|(\s:3\s)|(\s:3$)/g`

`^` is an anchor which matches `:3\s` to the beginning of the string.

`$` is an anchor which matches `\s:3` to the end of the string.

`\s` matches whitespace.

`|` is the pipe operator which acts as a logical OR operator between the different capture groups.

Comment: thank you its work for my code its would be `var f = ["(^:3\\s)|(\\s:3\\s)|(\\s:3$)" , ..... ]` because i use  `new RegExp`
more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the spaces from your emoji regex.

```js
var f = ["(:3)", "(:P)", "\(:star:\)"];
var r = ["[sadface]", "[toungeface]", "[staremoji]"];

var re = function(s) {
  return new RegExp(s, 'g');
};

s = "hello :3 how are you :P dwdwd :star: :3";
console.log(s);
for (var n in f) {
  var m;
  if ((m = re(f[n]).exec(s)) !== null) {
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
      s = s.replace(match, r[n]);
    });
  }
}

console.log(s);
```

Comment: If you read the question he says that if it's found in middle of string there must be space between word and emoji. Your code will also work for hello:3 with hello[sadface] which it should not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var content = "hello :D how are you :P dwdwd";
content = content.replace(/((:D|:P))/g,function(match){
  var result = "";
  
  var index = -1;
  switch(match)
  {
    case ":D":
      result = "happy";
      index = 0
      break;
    case ":P":
      result =  "smilie";
      index = 1
      break;
  }
  if(index != -1)
  {
    return "<img src='http://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/"+index+".png'>";
  }
  return result;
});
console.log(content);
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

I created a more generic solution, starting with the mapping of emojis to the relevant names.  Rather than two lists that need to be kept in synch, I used a single object:

```
const emojis = {
  '(c)': 'a9',
  '(r)': 'ae',
  '(tm)': '2122'
  //, ...
};
```

This strikes me as a much more useful structure to work with, but the code below could easily be altered to deal with the two-lists version.

Then I use a helper function to escape characters which are not allowed as plain text in Regular Expression by prepending them with `\`:

```
const escapeSpecials = (() => {
  const specials = ['/', '.', '*', '+', '?', '|', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\'];
  const reg = new RegExp('(\\' + specials.join('|\\') + ')', 'g');
  return str => str.replace(reg, '\\$1'); 
})();
```

Then I have the key function:

```
const replaceStringsWith = (emojis, convert) => str => Object.keys(emojis).reduce(
  (str, em) => str.replace(new RegExp(`(^|\\s+)(${escapeSpecials(em)})($|\\s+)`, 'g'), 
                           (m, a, b, c) =>  `${a}${convert(emojis[b], b)}${c}`),
  str
);
```

This takes an object containing string/replacement pairs and a converter function which accepts the replacement and gives you back the final form.  It returns a function which takes a string, and then searches for any matches on the keys of the object (properly checked for strings or string ends), replacing them with the result of calling the converter on the object's value for the particular key.

Thus we can do:

```
const toUrl = (name) => `<img src='http://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/${name}.png'>`; 
const replaceEmojis = replaceStringsWith(emojis, toUrl)
```

and call it as

```
const s = "This is Copyright (c) 2017, FooBar is (tm) BazCo (r)";
replaceEmojis(s); //=>
// `This is Copyright <img src='http://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/a9.png'>
// 2017, FooBar is <img src='http://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/2122.png'>
// BazCo <img src='http://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/ae.png'>`
```

Note that the converter also takes a second parameter.  So you could instead use

```
const toUrl = (name, emoji) => 
  `<img src='http://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/${name}.png' title='${emoji}'>`;
```

to get

```
//=> `This is Copyright <img    
// src='http://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/a9.png' title='(c)'>
// 2017, FooBar is <img src='http://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/2122.png'
// title='(tm)'> BazCo <img src='http://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/ae.png' title='(r)'>"
```